# What should I set my Content-Security-Policy to?

Tags: 8, http-request

I'm using Drupal 8, and I currently use

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; nosniff"
```

However, this causes bugs, such as Google Analytics not working and the textbox mysteriously disappearing from the Edit page. What should I do?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L97wtYCqfwM . this guy explains clearly about CSP.

Answer (score 3):

The policy needs to contain every domain where assets are loaded from, which will vary depending on which services your site uses such as a CDN or third party JavaScript widgets.

For Google Analytics, it must be able to connect to `www.google-analytics.com`, and `stats.g.doubleclick.net` if Display Features tracking is enabled.
The [*Google Analytics*](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module also requires the `unsafe-inline` policy value, since it injects the analytics snippet directly on the page.
[*Googalytics*](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga) is an alternative built specifically for Drupal 8 that works without `unsafe-inline`.

Core also currently requires 'unsafe-inline' for scripts in element attributes due to its use of CKEditor 4 (see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2789139)

---

In order to test a Content Security Policy without impacting the functionality of your site, first use the `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` header instead.  This will make the browser report violations of the policy in the browser console and to the `report-uri` address, without blocking the content on the page.  Once you have a policy that works without violations, change the header to `Content-Security-Policy`.

You can also provide both headers at the same time, allowing you to test changes without the risk of breaking functionality.

[Report-uri.io](https://report-uri.io/) provides a free logging service that you can use to collect violations of both your enforced and report-only rules, and audit for any changes you may need to make.
They also have a wizard utility to help setup your policy for the first time.

---

Setting up a policy in Drupal 8 is also easier with the [Content Security Policy module](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp).  It integrates with Drupal 8's libraries system to automatically add script and style sources, provides an admin UI that validates your settings, provides a local handler for report violations, and will apply some optimizations to shorten the policy if possible.